# Decodificar entidades HTML num string em Python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, htmlentities

Estou usando Python 3 para acessar uma API web. A resposta das requisições vêm no padrão JSON e o meu problema é que um dos Strings vem codificado com entidades em HTML (especificamente acentuação).

Por exemplo:

```
"orienta&ccedil;&atilde;o-a-objetos"
```

Existe algum *parser* que me devolva os strings com os caracteres HTML resolvidos?

Answer (score 4):

Encontrei essa aqui, para Python 3.4+ :

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('orienta&ccedil;&atilde;o-a-objetos')
'orientação-a-objetos'
```

No caso de Python 3 (versões anteriores à 3.4):

```
>>> import html.parser
>>> h = html.parser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('orienta&ccedil;&atilde;o-a-objetos')
'orientação-a-objetos'
```

Answer (score 0):

Também é possível utilizar o Beautifulsoup, bs4 para Py3+ ou bs para Py3-, que além de converter a codificação HTML para ascii, também permite trabalhar com os elementos HTML individualmente (se houverem na string de entrada).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s='orienta&ccedil;&atilde;o-a-objetos'
t = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
print(t.get_text())
```